# Unable to query Google Search Console API using a Service Account

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-search-console, service-accounts

I need to retrieve some data from Google Search Console (Webmaster Tools) using a service account.

So far I've been able to retrieve an `access_token` for the service account which I need to append to the url of the request. The problem is that I can't find a way to do so, this is the code i'm using:

```
function retrieveSearchesByQuery(token)
    {
        gapi.client.webmasters.searchanalytics.query(
        {
            'access_token': token,
            'siteUrl': 'http://www.WEBSITE.com',
            'fields': 'responseAggregationType,rows',
            'resource': {
                'startDate': formatDate(cSDate),
                'endDate': formatDate(cEDate),
                'dimensions': [
                    'date'
                ]
            }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .then(null, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

This is the url called by the function:

```
https://content.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.WEBSITE.com/searchAnalytics/query?fields=responseAggregationType%2Crows&alt=json"
```

Instead it should be something like this:

```
https://content.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.WEBSITE.com/searchAnalytics/query?fields=responseAggregationType%2Crows&alt=json&access_token=XXX"
```

The `gapi.client.webmasters.searchanalytics.query` doesn't recognize `'access_token'` as a valid key thus it doesn't append it to the url and that's why I get a `401 Unauthorized` as response.

If I use `'key'` instead of `'access_token'` the parameter gets appended to the url but `'key'` is used for `OAuth2` authentication so the service account token I pass is not valid.

Does anyone have a solution or a workaround for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your application requests private data, the request must be authorized by an authenticated user who has access to that data. As specified in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/how-tos/authorizing) of the Search Console API, your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported.

If you application is [correctly configured](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication), when using the Google API, an authenticated request looks exactly like an unauthenticated request. As stated in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication), if the application has received an OAuth 2.0 token, the JavaScript client library includes it in the request automatically.

You're mentioning that you have retrieved an `access_token`, if correctly received, the API client will automatically send this token for you, you don't have to append it yourself.

A very basic workflow to authenticate and once authenticated, send a request would looks like the following code. The  Search Console API can use the following scopes: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly`.

```
var clientId = 'YOUR CLIENT ID';
var apiKey = 'YOUR API KEY';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters';

function auth() {
  // Set the API key.
  gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);

  // Start the auth process using our client ID & the required scopes.
  gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: clientId,
      scope: scopes
  })
  .then(function () {
    // We're authenticated, let's go...
    // Load the webmasters API, then query the API
    gapi.client.load('webmasters', 'v3')
      .then(retrieveSearchesByQuery);
  });
}

// Load the API client and auth library
gapi.load('client:auth2', auth);
```

At this point, your `retrieveSearchesByQuery` function will need to be modified since it doesn't need to get a token by argument anymore in order to pass it in the query. The JavaScript client library should include it in the request automatically.

You can also use the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/webmasters/v3/webmasters.searchanalytics.query) to check what parameters are supported for a specific query and check the associated request.

If you need to use an externally generated access token, which should be the case with a Service Account, you need to use the [`gapi.auth.setToken` method](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthsetToken) to sets the [OAuth 2.0 token object](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#oauth-20-token-object) yourself for the application:

```
gapi.auth.setToken(token_Object);
```