# Shared file user can't access files using drive.file scope In google drive API

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

when a shared user is login in App. shared file can't access. API return "no files found'.

```
var SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "profile"];
function createPermissions(fileId, body) {
  gapi.client.load("drive", "v3", function() {
    gapi.client.drive.permissions
      .create({
        fileId: fileId,
        resource: body
      })
      .then(function(res) {
        //console.log(res);
        Swal.fire("Success!", "File has been success shared!", "success");
        // do something
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        //console.log(err);
        Swal.fire({
          icon: "error",
          title: "Oops...",
          text: "Something went wrong! Plese try agian later!!",
          footer: ""
        });
        // do something
      });
  });
}
```

The above code is working fine, the file is successfully shared but the shared user gets email notification of share file and when a shared user clicks on a shared file email file is access in google drive. Ie: Manoj (App owner) upload file in google APP(google drive API) and share file with "Rigal". Rigal gets a shared file email notification and file also display(access ) in his google drive. But when Rigal login in App (google drive API) he can't view (access) shared file.
Thanks

Comment: Do you encounter the same problem if Manoj shares the files manually with Rigal, without using the API? When the shared user clicks  in the email on the link to the file that has been shared with him, is the file / his drive being opened with the same account with which the file has been shared? Or maybe the user has a second account?

Comment: Hello, @ziganotschka Yes, I have checked manually to share a file with rigal and it is successfully shared After when I log in with API shared file not display using API.

Comment: So the file is succesfully shared, but does not show up when Rigal tries to access it programmatically with the API? Can you please provide the code that Rigal uses to access the file?

Comment: Hello, @ziganotschka I following https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js link to get files from google drive.
I have change var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"; in the above code example.

Comment: Can the user access the file with different scopes, e.g. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`? The documentation https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes specifies that `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` only allows you to "View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app"

Comment: @ziganotschka Using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive scope we access all files But we have to access only app-specific google drive files(File uploaded and shared using an app) instead of all files. So we have to use only https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file scope.

Comment: Unfortunately the scope googleapis.com/auth/drive.file will allow Rigal only to list files that have been opened or created with HIS APP by HIM, not the ones Manoj shared with him.

Comment: Thanks, @ziganotschka for your quick reply. Is there any alternative solution to solve the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Search results for listing files can be filtered by implementing the search query [`q`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)**

- If Rigal specifies for `q` 'sharedWithMe' - only the files will be listed, that have been shared with Rigal by someone else.
- If Rigal addionally specifies `'test@example.org' in owners`, this will allow to eliminate from the results the files that have been shared with Rigal by someone else.
- It is not possible to distinguish between files that have been shared with Rigal by Manoj's App, rather than by Manoj manually, unless Monoj's App makes use of a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts), eventually with [impersonation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), for sharing the file with Rigal.

A sample based on the Drive v3 API quickstart you use:

```
function listFiles() {
        gapi.client.drive.files.list({
          'q': "sharedWithMe and 'test@example.org' in owners"
          'pageSize': 10,
          'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
        }).then(function(response) {
          appendPre('Files:');
          var files = response.result.files;
          if (files && files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              appendPre(file.name + ' (' + file.id + ')');
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No files found.');
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: thanks for your help . Would you please provide a code sample?

Comment: I provided a sample based on the quickstart you are using.

Comment: Hello @ziganotschka 
I have followed the below tutorial for upload/access/share files on google drive using google drive API.

https://bytutorial.com/tutorials/google-api/introduction-to-google-drive-api-using-javascript

Would you please suggest how to authenticate the app using a service account?

Thanks

Comment: This is more tricky - you need to create a service account in the first place - as described here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts and here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts A tutorial how to implement it in JS: https://dev.to/mornir/create-a-service-account-to-authenticate-with-google-5b1k Basically, you need to implement the functions `getCredentials()` and `getDrive()` and then replace ` gapi.client.drive.permissions.create` through `getDrive().permissions.create`

Comment: Hello,@ziganotschka
I have created a service account and follow steps. I have checked the below tutorial but it's based on Node Js. We need a javascript code directly executed in a browser.

Comment: This post should be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38717987/11599789

Comment: Hello @ziganotschka 
I followed below Tutorial for API tasks. 
https://bytutorial.com/tutorials/google-api/introduction-to-google-drive-api-using-javascript.I have so many hours but didn't get a good example of google API service account. Would you please suggest which changes needed to the user service account as per the above tutorial?

Comment: Unfortunately this link does not work for me. Since creating a service account goes beyond the scope of your initial question, I would suggest that you create a new post with an adequate title - to increase visibility - and show your efforts to create a service account and explain where you got stuck. Then me and other users can help you better to solve your doubts.

Comment: Hello @ziganotschka
https://bytutorial.com/tutorials/google-api/introduction-to-google-drive-api-using-javascript

Comment: Hello, @ziganotschka I have created a service account but the issue is I can't find a good example of generating a token, Authentication, get file list using a service account. Would you please help me if you have a demo example please share code with me or check this link https://bytutorial.com/tutorials/google-api/introduction-to-google-drive-api-using-javascript  I followed this link for google drive API, check above tutorial and guide me which changes need to do. Thanks